# How to render MAthml tags in reactjs from string?

Tags: reactjs, mathml

My code is not working. It's also showing a warning for "react-mathjax-preview":

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-mathjax-preview'.
```

My code is:

```
import React from "react";
import MathJax from "react-mathjax-preview";
import ReactHtmlParser from "react-html-parser";

export const renderText = (text) => {
  const mathtype = <MathJax math={String.raw`${text}`} />;
  const texttype = ReactHtmlParser(text);

  let textType = "";

  const loop = (string) =>
    string.forEach((item) => {
      if (item?.type !== "math") {
        if (item?.props?.children?.length > 0) {
          return loop(item?.props?.children);
        }
      } else {
        textType = "math";
      }
    });

  loop(texttype);

  if (textType !== "math") {
    return texttype;
  } else {
    return mathtype;
  }
};
```

Comment: It sounds like you're saying you can't find the module, which means you need to check that it's installed in your `package.json` and doesn't have anything to do with your function.

Comment: Yes its installed  "react-mathjax-preview": "^2.2.4",

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting, then?

Comment: Not Giving any error just not rendering mathml (mathematical equation) on webpage

Comment: Geeting this text <p><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mi>x</mi><msup><mi>e</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>=</mo><msqrt><mi>y</mi></msqrt><mspace linebreak="newline">&nbsp;</mspace><msup><mi>z</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>=</mo><msub><mi>r</mi><mn>3</mn></msub></math></p>

Comment: Need your help.

Comment: Please don't add code to comments, edit your question and add the additional information to the question as if it'd been there originally so that we're not forced to read every comment. Don't add "edited" or "updated" type tags as we can tell what changed and when.